# Excel standard encoding

Tags: php, excel, encoding

I take data from SQL server.
I create a long string with spaces between fields and newlines for new rows.
Then I convert the string with iconv from windows-1255 to UTF-8 and save the string to a file test.xls.
When I open the file in OpenOffice spreadsheet the table is displayed correctly if I choose the UTF encoding.
But opening the file in MS excel, the fields are displayed correctly, but Hebrew text is not.

My question is: In which encoding should I save the file to be displayed correctly in Excel?

Comment: You could try ISO-8859-1. Solved a problem I had a long time ago

Comment: @OptimusCrime: good luck encoding Hebrew text in ISO-8859-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) to create actual Excel documents rather than mislabelled CSV. The problem is that CSV has no encoding metadata, and which encoding Excel will use depends on the system settings (i.e. there *is no* "standard encoding").

Comment: about PHPEXcel: is there a way to use it partly, it is really big(

Comment: @lvil: Yes, it should be possible to leave out the directory Classes\PHPExcel\Shared\PDF, which is used for PDF generation and responsible for most of the bulk of the actual library. If you unzip the download, it's about 110MB, but about 90 of that is documentation, and 16 is the PDF stuff.